# Cannot delete comment on Youtube video via API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to delete followiing comment **z12mdhjgxrfgtpf3d231jrz5vo3jdj0lo** on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiPlav1ZRtA) but the response code is 400. I'm using token of the channel's admin with *https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl* scope as it required by [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/delete).

The request is:

```
DELETE https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?id=z12mdhjgxrfgtpf3d231jrz5vo3jdj0lo&alt=json

{
    "query_params": { 
        "id": "z12mdhjgxrfgtpf3d231jrz5vo3jdj0lo",
        "alt": "json"
    }
}
```

The response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.comment",
    "reason": "processingFailure",
    "message": "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "id"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid."
 }
}
```

What is wrong with the request?

That's token debug info:

```
{
    issued_to: "493985796851.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    audience: "493985796851.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    user_id: "109704411339866376304",
    scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload",
    expires_in: 2452,
    access_type: "offline"
}
```

Comment: Seems like you are not authorized to delete that comment. Are you absolutely sure your access token is valid and for the right channel?

Comment: I think so. I added token info to the question and it has required 'force-ssl' scope and user 109704411339866376304 is the owner of the channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're not able to delete the comment is that you're using [Comments.delete](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/delete) to remove comment which was written by other users . `Comments.delete` only deletes your own comments in your video.

To delete comment of other users, use [Comments.setModerationStatus](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/setModerationStatus) and set moderationStatus to "`rejected`".

So just repeat what you did but this time using `Comments.setModerationStatus`. There's a Try-it in the link for testing purposes.